# Some issue with const and json

Tags: javascript, json, ethereum

deployedTo does not seem to be recognized there are no errors though. just the system fail to recognised. deployedTo is suppose to = the deployed address of my smart contract. I tired stringify, parse , cant seem to figure out what is going on. If i replace deployedTo with '00dsdsdsds22s323...' ie directly with the address string the thing work fine.

```
import web3 from './web3';
import InsurancePoolFactory from  './build/InsurancePoolFactory.json';
require('dotenv').config();
const { deployedTo } = process.env;

const instance = new web3.eth.Contract(
  JSON.parse(InsurancePoolFactory.interface),
  deployedTo // the issue lies here
);

export default instance;
```

thanks in advance to all whom help.

Comment: Did you try declaring it regularly instead of using destructuring? `const DEPLOYED_TO = process.env.DEPLOYED_TO`

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is to test whether `deployedTo` is actually read from environment, like this:

```js
import web3 from './web3';
import InsurancePoolFactory from  './build/InsurancePoolFactory.json';
require('dotenv').config();
const { deployedTo } = process.env;

console.log(deployedTo); // NEW

const instance = new web3.eth.Contract(
  JSON.parse(InsurancePoolFactory.interface),
  deployedTo // the issue lies here
);

export default instance;
```

If it is not '00dsdsdsds22s323...', but `undefined`, you know your problem.

If it is indeed undefined, check the `.env` file, sometimes people make silly typos there.

Comment: Hey @, accept my answer if it helped you. Thanks! :)